# Leer un archivo CSV en c# de mas de 2GB

Tags: c#

Tengo dos formas de leerlo , pero las dos se demoran horas y nunca me entregan un resultado de si finalizo o no , no se si sea problema de memoria. Su ayuda por favor.
1.-

```
 using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fileStream,4096))
                    {
                        var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader(fileStream, new ExcelReaderConfiguration()
                        {

                            FallbackEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252),

                            AutodetectSeparators = new char[] { ',' },

                        });
                        DataSet results = reader.AsDataSet();

                    }
```

2.-

```
    string line2;
    string[] row2;
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
      {         
         using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs,80000))
         {
           using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
           {
            while ((line2 = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
               row2 = line2.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
               parsedData.Add(row2);
               
               contador++;
                 }
                sr.DiscardBufferedData();               
                sr.Dispose();
               }
              }

             }

          }
```

Comment: probaste usar `yield return`? es para que te vaya devolviendo resultados mientras procesa. No se cuanta memoria tienes, pero estarias cargando 2 gb en tu memoria ram.

Comment: Iba a dar algunas indicaciones, pero parece que no te tomas la molestia en marcar como correctas las respuestas que te dan. Revisa el [tour] para ver como funciona este sitio.